# How to add a link (Like, comment) at the facebook app wall post

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have a Facebook application where I am using it in Windows phone 7 application.

I am done with share on Facebook option through my mobile application. I want to add an extra link at the bottom of my application wall post (beside the like and comment links present)

How can I achieve this? Which setting need to be set in the application settings?

Answer (score 0):

The docs for integrating share functionality are at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share.
However:

> We don't recommend the Share button
>   for new developers. If you aren't
>   already using the Share button, we
>   recommend you migrate to the Like
>   button and Open Graph protocol instead
>   of Share for sharing pages from your
>   website. The Like button is simpler to
>   user and is the recommended solution
>   moving forward.

Because this is implemented in HTML & JS with Facebook's own scripts you'de need to look at usingt a WebBrowserr control to embed this funcitonality on your page.